# An item with the same key has already been added - SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core

I have the following stored procedure that I call from EF Core 5, but when I try to call it, I get the following error

> An item with the same key has already been added. Key: EntityID

The stored procedure returns 5 rows. Two items have two movements and one item has one movement.

```
SELECT
    [i].[EntityID], 
    [i].[Alicuota], 
    [i].[AlicuotaType], 
    [i].[BrandID], 
    [i].[Code], 
    [i].[CreateByID], 
    [i].[CreateOn], 
    [i].[Description], 
    [i].[EnterpriseID], 
    [i].[IsDeleted], 
    [i].[MeasureType], 
    [i].[MinStock], 
    [i].[Name], 
    [i].[Type], 
    [i].[UpdateByID], 
    [i].[UpdateOn], 
    [t].[EntityID], 
    [t].[Balance], 
    [t].[BranchOfficeID], 
    [t].[CreateByID], 
    [t].[CreateOn], 
    [t].[Date], 
    [t].[EmployeeID], 
    [t].[IsDeleted], 
    [t].[IsEditable], 
    [t].[ItemID], 
    [t].[Notes], 
    [t].[Number], 
    [t].[Quantity], 
    [t].[Type], 
    [t].[UpdateByID], 
    [t].[UpdateOn], 
    [t].[VoucherID] 
FROM 
    [Items] AS [i] 
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         [m].[EntityID], 
         [m].[Balance], 
         [m].[BranchOfficeID], 
         [m].[CreateByID], 
         [m].[CreateOn], 
         [m].[Date], 
         [m].[EmployeeID], 
         [m].[IsDeleted], 
         [m].[IsEditable], 
         [m].[ItemID], 
         [m].[Notes], 
         [m].[Number], 
         [m].[Quantity], 
         [m].[Type], 
         [m].[UpdateByID], 
         [m].[UpdateOn], 
         [m].[VoucherID], 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [m].[BranchOfficeID], [m].[ItemID] 
                            ORDER BY [m].[CreateOn] DESC) AS LAST_ROW 
     FROM 
         [Movements] AS [m] 
     WHERE 
         [m].[IsDeleted] <> CAST(1 AS bit)) AS [t] ON [i].[EntityID] = [t].[ItemID] 
                                                   AND LAST_ROW = 1 
WHERE 
    [i].[EnterpriseID] = 'EMPRESA-1' 
    AND [i].[IsDeleted] <> CAST(1 AS bit) 
ORDER BY 
    [i].[EntityID], [t].[EntityID]
```

From Net Core 5:

```
_databaseContext.Set<ItemSP>().FromSqlRaw("SP_NAME {0}", "PARAMETER").ToList();
```

**EDIT:**

```
An item with the same key has already been added. Key: EntityID
System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added. Key: EntityID
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.TryInsert(TKey key, TValue value, InsertionBehavior behavior)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.FromSqlQueryingEnumerable`1.BuildIndexMap(IReadOnlyList`1 columnNames, DbDataReader dataReader)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.FromSqlQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.InitializeReader(DbContext _, Boolean result)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.FromSqlQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
```

[image]

```
The Item '2B9C0BF2-8585-4710-A4AB-5C91A99F864A' has two movements
The Item '849EA1AB-B7D3-4A4D-A439-252169AB0266' has one movement
The Item 'AB6FBB7E-A5D8-4246-A0D1-875EFB862727' has two movements

public class ItemSP
{
    public string EntityID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Code { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public decimal? MinStock { get; set; }

    public MeasureTypeEnum MeasureType { get; set; }

    public IVAAlicuotaTypeEnum AlicuotaType { get; set; }

    public decimal Alicuota { get; set; }

    public ItemTypeEnum Type { get; set; }

    public string BrandID { get; set; }

    public Brand Brand { get; set; }

    public string EnterpriseID { get; set; }

    public Enterprise Enterprise { get; set; }

    public List<ItemPrice> Prices { get; set; }

    public List<ItemCategory> Categories { get; set; }

    public List<StockMovement> Movements { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but the code example shows signs of possible sql injection attack through ````"PARAMETER"````. Worth to check.

Comment: My guess is this query is returning multiple rows with the same `EntityID` value.

Comment: @DavidG Yes, that is correct. What I want is to map that result to a list of Items with their movements

Comment: @cly, `FromSqlRaw` parameterizes the interpolated string per the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql), avoiding SQL injection.

Comment: Can you add the entity definition and stored procedure results., as well as the call stack of the exception? If you could simplify the scenario by having fewer columns for the repro that would be helpful.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Check the edit. The image is incomplete is it necessary all? 
 Thx!

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I found the error, the problem is the repeated columns name, but how do I return the movements?

Comment: With a second query or procedure.

Comment: In the procedure